# Отображение коллекции с помощью XAML

Tags: xaml, связывание-данных, c#

У меня имеется коллекция, которую необходимо отобразить пользователю. Я использую связывание данных. В результате получаю примерно такой код:

```
// C#
class Data 
{
    public List MyCollection { get; set; }
}

<!-- XAML -->
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}"
    SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
/>
```

Проблема архитектурная: как сделать так, чтобы при смене выделенного элемента вызывался метод текущего контекста данных, а также как из контекста данных менять выделенный элемент, не привязываясь к имени или обработчику, т.е. к конкретному отображению?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данную задачу легко решить с помощь привязки данных.

```
// C#
class Data 
{
    public List MyCollection { get; set; }
    public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
 }

 <!-- XAML -->
 <ListBox
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" 
     SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" 
     SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
 />
```

В XAML появилась новая привязка данных к свойству SelectedItem. В секциях set и get свойства SelectedItem добавляем нужный нам код обработчиков. Также можно увидеть, что привязка двунаправленная, следовательно, если мы напишем

```
SelectedItem = 2;
```

то будет выбран второй элемент в списке при условии его существования, при этом все изменения коснутся и отображения.

Comment: Без реализации интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged двунаправленная связь вроде невозможна:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx